# Use Star-Trekky noise for chat notifications instead of the "fart" on chat.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, chat

I like the *Star-Trek*-esque *beedeebeeboop* as a chat notification on http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/ far more so than the fart/raspberry noise that https://chat.stackexchange.com/ uses. It is much more audible over my music and occasional gastric distress.

Can StackExchange just rip off MSO (or either of the SU/SF sounds Mike linked)?

Comment: +1 for the onomatopoeia - *beedeebeeboop*

Comment: +1, but isn't it rather a *beedeeboop*? (leaving to check)

Comment: There's no one in right now. Rats.

Comment: @Pekka You can ping yourself.

Comment: It seems like a stretch to call the chat.SE notification a "fart"...

Comment: Chat.SE's ping sound is the only thing in the Stack Exchange network that reminds me of Windows 3.1...

Comment: +1 for legitimate use of "fart" on StackExchange

Answer (score 10):

For reference, [chat.SE](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/se.mp3) versus [chat.MSO](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/meta.mp3). The ones from [chat.SU](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/su.mp3) and [chat.SF](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/sf.mp3) are still available from when those existed as well -- personally I like chat.SF the most, then chat.SU, then chat.SE. chat.MSO's is too long

Comment: Thanks for this. Conclusion: I think it's more a *beedeebooboop*.

Comment: The links are dead. Welp, cannot understand what they meant by *beedeebooboop*...